# teamviewer is not working on ubuntu 16.04 / Cannot access teamviewer on ubuntu 16.04 / Teamviewer is blank on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 and teamviewer and I using the teamviewer for last 2 days. Suddenly the screen went blank and cannot access anything. If I try to connect(I setup constant password while TV working), The whole screen is blank(full black) to the remote user.

Really appreciated your help!

[image: screen shot Reference 1]

[image: screen shot Reference 2]